# Actual size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screen-size

I have made a JFrame clearly through Java and set the size so that it is as large as possible on the screen.  For instance I will use Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() to set the size of the JFrame, but because of the menu bar / dock etc. (in windows and mac) it gets resized to fit the screen.  How would I be able to get this new dimension, which the JFrame defaults to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303305/window-resize-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I am understanding your question correctly. But if you want to get the size of the screen minus the menu bar / task bar, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123735/get-effective-screen-size-from-java) answer could help.

If you simply want to get the new dimensions of your JFrame then use:

```
yourFrame.getSize();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for sorry about the re-ask.

Answer (score 3):

To maximize the JFrame, you add maximized both to the extended state.

```
frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

On Windows XP, this maximization takes into account the Windows status bar.  However, the horizontal calculation is a few pixels off, and you won't see all of the side borders.

I've not tried this on Windows 7 or Unix.

You should also set a JFrame size, in case the user clicks on the maximize / restore size button (the middle button on a Windows JPanel).