# How do I test for a change in the size of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make everything in my window change size when the window size is changed. I am making a custom UI and need to set the layout to null, but I also don't want the window to have a never-changing size. My solution to this is to figure out when the size has changed then update the components of the frame to match that size. How can I do that?

Comment: `How can I do that?` By using layouts.

Comment: Look at how layout managers work - follow their lead.  In fact, if the UI is "so complex" that you feel that you need a `null` layout, I would suggest that you're wrong, in part, and what you might want to consider is either a different layout manager (or combination of), including MigLayout or writing your own

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I understand, you can use an componentListener, adding it to JFrame.
I use it as:

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
          e.getComponent().getWidth();
          e.getComponent().getHeight();
      }

      @Override
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){
      }

      @Override
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){
      }

      @Override
      public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){
      }
    });
```

Comment: Wrong solution. The proper solution is to use layout managers. By using appropriate layout managers components will automatically resize. The fact that you think you need to write code when the frame size changes means you don't understand the power and benefits of layout managers. (1-) for suggesting the ComponentListener. Use Swing the way it was designed to be used. It will prevent future problems.

Comment: @camickr the proper solution is the solution that works for your problem.
Sometimes is impossible to use layout managers.
For example, I work with one project that was implemented using custom componentes, that is not compatible with JFrame or components like JPanel, JButton, JMessage, and others... That project uses JFrame only to paint application using Graphics of paint method, is impossible to change anything, so using layout managers is impossible. So, in this case, the proper solution is ComponentListener, no other option os allowed.

Comment: *the proper solution is the solution that works for your problem* - Of course there is always more than one solution. This site promotes the usage of Swing the way it is designed to be used. The fact that the OP has to ask a basic question like this indicates they are not familiar with Swing and layout managers. The OP's requirement is to match the components to the size of the frame which is exactly what layout managers are for. Even if you think you have some kind of weird layout requirement you can create a custom layout manager as was already suggested.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a componentResized method in a ComponentListener (or ComponentAdapter).

This was explained before:
[Window resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303305/window-resize-event)